Increasing Precision of Eigenvectors (Matrix with Large Eigenvalue)
I am currently using scipy.linalg.eigh to find the eigenvectors/eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix. I found that as I increase the size of the matrix, the eigenvectors started losing precision. Specifically, I found that after applying the original matrix on the eigenvector, dividing by its eigenvalue and subtracting the eigenvector again, I would get an array of values significantly greater than 0. Another important fact is that M has one eigenvalue that is significantly larger (around 10 orders of magnitude) than the other eigenvalues, which I believe is leading to the numerical inconsistency.
I saw some posts online saying that I could try projecting out the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue, so I've tried something like:
eigen_proj = eigenvectors[:,0] - (eigenvectors[:,0] @ eigenvectors[:,29])/(eigenvectors[:,29] @ eigenvectors[:,29]) * eigenvectors[:,29]
where as an example, eigenvectors[:,29] corresponds to the largest eigenvalue, but this has not really done much for my results. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, or people can offer some other advice.
